# Cocoa WebView On Navigate?

Tags: cocoa, webview, navigation

I am working on a Cocoa WebView based browser application.

Basically, I would like to have it so when the user navigates to a url, for example:
http://a/b.php, by clicking on a link on the previous page of a website, my application intercepts the "on navigate" event and changes the URL to http://a/b.php?enableapi=1

Any ideas??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign an object as the web view's `WebPolicyDelegate` and implement the `webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:` method.

In that method, you must call one of the `WebPolicyDecisionListener` protocol methods on the object that is passed as the `decisionlistener` parameter to the method. The three `WebPolicyDecisionListener` protocol methods are `ignore`, `use` or `download`.

You can then pass `ignore` to the listener and handle the link some other way for those links you're interested in intercepting.